# jquery cycle lite images breaking out of containing element

Tags: jquery, slideshow, padding

Test page here: [clicky click](http://www.oichigo.com/test/)

I'm trying to add 8px padding within my slideshow images container in order to create a white border.

This works great for the non-slideshow content ( check the 1st and last tabs at the top ) but not for the images that are being used in the cycle lite slideshow. ( 2 middle tabs at the top )

I can see it's to do with the slideshow using absolute positioning but can't quite figure out a way around it.

I want the padding on the container so the image is squeezed down within.

The images are sized with max-width 100% and scale up / down below 420px browser width so I don't really want to be using pixel based dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can place each image inside a div, add the padding to the img and cycle the divs.. That should work.

Here is an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/5VcNV/